# To create a submit form in wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I just had installed wordpress also I had went through HelloDolly plugin and its code. I would like to make a page which contains a submit form .Upon submitting the data should be inserted to db into any table. How should i do this,Where should i start,Pleas Help..THanks

Comment: Do you want to make this in plugin? details plz ....

Comment: Yes as a plugin, actually to learn how to make plugins.

Comment: I had understood "HelloDOlly" plugin

Comment: Related - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/60758/25035

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) could be your starting point.
[Here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/04/xxx-massive-wordpress-tutorial-collection.html) is best source of learning for wordpress.

Examples:

[Contact form without plugin](http://trevordavis.net/blog/wordpress-jquery-contact-form-without-a-plugin)

[Create a Custom WordPress Plugin From Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/)

Comment: ok to create a submit form do i need to write the html code inside a function in plugin page right. @DEv

Comment: you can create a new pages for that.